# Emmet code for generating HTML code as ul , followed by 3 li with a href and img within ..

Tags: emmet

What is the code to produce the following:

I'm using visual studio 2013 with  web essential installed...

I need  a   ul with 3 li with  an  and img inside...

```
<ul class="gallery">
<li>
    <a href="../upload/files/image-1" class="fb" rel="gallery">
        <img src="../upload/files/item-1" alt="Foto" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="../upload/files/image-2" class="fb" rel="gallery">
        <img src="../upload/files/item-2" alt="Foto" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="../upload/files/image-3" class="fb" rel="gallery">
        <img src="../upload/files/item-3" alt="Foto" />
    </a>
</li>
```

thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ul.gallery>li*3>a[href=../upload/files/image-$][class=fb][rel=gallery]>img[src=../upload/files/item-$][alt=Foto]
```